# Average of each column in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, average

I'm new to R and still learning. I have a matrix with 100 columns and I need to calculate the average of each column and store all those values for further calculations. Each column has 5 numbers and after this step i'm supposed to have 100 new values. Also, please let me know if the replicate() function is a viable way to do this in just one line.

Comment: just do `colMeans(your_matrix)`

Answer (score 5):

```
colMeans(DF)
```

Is a highly optimized function for exactly this purpose.